Почему Скрипт python не видит установленный модуль?
Установил модуль Crypto.
(central-server-py3.10) PS C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\bot\central_server> pip install Crypto

Requirement already satisfied: Crypto in c:\users\admin\appdata\local\pypoetry\cache\virtualenvs\central-server-6rgdxp4w-py3.10\lib\site-packages (1.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: Naked in c:\users\admin\appdata\local\pypoetry\cache\virtualenvs\central-server-6rgdxp4w-py3.10\lib\site-packages (from Crypto) (0.1.32)
Requirement already satisfied: shellescape in c:\users\admin\appdata\local\pypoetry\cache\virtualenvs\central-server-6rgdxp4w-py3.10\lib\site-packages (from Crypto) (3.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: requests in c:\users\admin\appdata\local\pypoetry\cache\virtualenvs\central-server-6rgdxp4w-py3.10\lib\site-packages (from Naked->Crypto) (2.32.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyyaml in c:\users\admin\appdata\local\pypoetry\cache\virtualenvs\central-server-6rgdxp4w-py3.10\lib\site-packages (from Naked->Crypto) (6.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer<4,>=2 in c:\users\admin\appdata\local\pypoetry\cache\virtualenvs\central-server-6rgdxp4w-py3.10\lib\site-packages (from requests->Naked->Crypto) (3.3.2)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in c:\users\admin\appdata\local\pypoetry\cache\virtualenvs\central-server-6rgdxp4w-py3.10\lib\site-packages (from requests->Naked->Crypto) (3.10)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<3,>=1.21.1 in c:\users\admin\appdata\local\pypoetry\cache\virtualenvs\central-server-6rgdxp4w-py3.10\lib\site-packages (from requests->Naked->Crypto) (2.2.3)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\users\admin\appdata\local\pypoetry\cache\virtualenvs\central-server-6rgdxp4w-py3.10\lib\site-packages (from requests->Naked->Crypto) (2024.8.30)

Пытаюсь запустить скрипт - пишет модуль не установлен. Почему так?
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\bot\central_server\main.py", line 3, in <module>
    from app.routers import register_routers
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\bot\central_server\app\routers\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from . import management, statistics
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\bot\central_server\app\routers\management.py", line 5, in <module>
    from app.utils.manager import Manager
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\bot\central_server\app\utils\manager.py", line 8, in <module>
    from app.services.sub_server import SubServer
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\bot\central_server\app\services\sub_server.py", line 3, in <module>
    from app.utils.crypto import encrypt_data, generate_auth
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\bot\central_server\app\utils\crypto.py", line 1, in <module>
    from Crypto.Cipher import AES
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Crypto '


«Установил модуль Crypto» — рекомендую сразу переставать путать модули и пакеты. Вы установили пакет Crypto, который содержит в себе модуль crypto, но вот модуля Crypto он не содержит. Ну а тот модуль Crypto, который вам нужен, находится в пакете pycryptodome (или в pycrypto, но его лучше не надо)

с этой библиотекой есть некие рофлы, скорее всего она называется PyCryptodome. Попробуй в консольку прописать вот так:
pip install pycryptodome

Попробуйте следующее:
pip uninstall crypto

pip uninstall pycrypto

А затем опять установите pycrypto:
pip install pycrypto

А вообще не советую использовать данную библиотеку, она считается не безопасной.
Лучше используйте pycryptodome

Здесь букет проблем.
Установите современную версию Питон. Это 3.12.6
Обновите установщик:
python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip

Команда установки модуля выглядит на сайте на самом деле так:
pip install pycrypto

А более правильно должна выглядеть так:
pip install -U --compile pycrypto

Прежде, чем применять модуль, надо бы хоть как-то сходить на сайт разработчика да глянуть чаво оно делает.
Избавьтесь от всех from, чем быстрее, тем лучше. Ограниченные импорты в половине случае причина "проблем".
Проконтролируйте импорты скриптов в программе. Это вторая половина причин для "проблем". Я вообще не пользуюсь, собираю финальный скрипт вручную. Это делается с помощью очень примитивного скрипта, но гарантирует мне отсутствие сюрпризов.
Рахитские среды типа Pycharm "сами себя не видят", не то что нужные файлы. Если хотите понять что происходит и почему, запустите свою программу автономно, как файл .py. Вот тогда и увидите, каково на самом деле её качество, отсутствие глюков и устойчивость.
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\bot\ - грубейшая неряшливость в организации рабочего процесса. Кто работает на десктопе? Где этому учат? Не смешивайте никогда данные и кашу ОС, никогда не работайте в каталогах с ограниченными правами доступа - это азы компьютерной грамотности.

"Установите современную версию Питон. Это 3.12.6" - современные версии - это все, у которых не наступил end of life (см. Status of Python versions). У 3.8 EOL наступит в октябре 2024 (т.е. очень скоро), поэтому считаем современными от 3.9 до 3.12. В октябре выйдет 3.13, и хотя она "как бы" будет современной, сразу на нее не нужно преходить, нужно подождать где-то полгода, пока основные библиотеки обновятся. Тупо смотреть, какая сейчас самая новая версия, и сразу обновляться на нее точно не нужно. Только если есть какие-то критичные исправления.

"Избавьтесь от всех from, чем быстрее, тем лучше." - это дичь, где такому учат? Не нужно использовать импорт через звездочку, а импорт конкретных имен через from - вполне нормален.

"Кто работает на десктопе?" - в целом соглашусь, но есть вопросы к формулировке "никогда не работайте в каталогах с ограниченными правами доступа" - я предполагаю, что вы имеете в виду, что не нужно работать в каталогах, где требуются админские права для запуска (типа Windows, Program Files), но как раз рабочий стол таким каталогам не относится.

А, ну и про "рахитские среды" забыл написать. PyCharm вполне нормальная среда, просто нужно минимальное понимание виртуальных сред, и как их настроить в PyCharm. В вопросе PyCharm вообще не упоминается, но вы каждый раз про нее пишите, видимо это какая-то ваша персональная боль. Максимум тут можно посочувствовать.
